# SwiftUI Stepper puts "." in Integers

Tags: swift, swiftui, stepper

```
Stepper(value: $year, in: 2018...2025){Text("Year: \(year)")}
```

Displays as `Year: 2.200` thousand-point with the thousand-point.

How can this thousand-point be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternate constructor for `Text`:

```
Text(verbatim: "Year: \(year)")
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of String interpolation:

```
Text("Year: \(year)")
```

Use String initialiser:

```
Text("Year: \(String(year))")
```